# How to build a nested object on handleChange with React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, nested

Good evening,
I have a onChange function name handleChange for a number of dinamically created inputs. What this does is to receive the event and then it does as it follows:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const updatedValues = [...values];
  updatedValues[e.target.dataset.id] = []
  updatedValues[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  setValues(updatedValues);
}
```

The first issue i'm finding here is that is building the object with the following structure:

```
[
  {name: "some_name"}
], 
[
  {lastname: "some_lastname"}
], 
[
  {email: "some_data"}
], 
[
  {phone: "some_phone"}
]
```

But the structure I want goes like this:

```
[
  { name: "some_name", lastname: "some_lastname", email: "some_email", phone: "some_phone"}
]
```

Next thing I wanna do, is to store NESTED components on new property named nested. I want it to be like this:

```
[
  { name: "some_name", lastname: "some_lastname", email: "some_email", phone: "some_phone", nested: [
    { value: "some_value", value2: "some_value2", value3: "some_value3"}
  ]}
]
```

The nested ones are being grabbed from a box of inputs. The box has a className of "nested" and it is at the same level as the first inputs. Inside of it I have the inputs that I want to nest.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an object map (i.e. an associative array of key-value pairs) you can write your `handleChange` callback as

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({}); // state is object

...

const handleChange = e => {
  const { dataset, name, value } = e.target;

  // Use a functional state update
  setValues(values => ({
    ...values,

    // update the correct dataset id
    [dataset.id]: {
      // shallow copy existing dataset values
      ...values[dataset.id],

      // if value is nested then update nested state value
      ...(dataset.nested
        ? {
            nested: {
              // shallow copy existing nested values
              ...values[dataset.id]?.nested,

              // update nested field value
              [name]: value
            }
          }
        : {
            // update unnested field value
            [name]: value
          })
    }
  }));
};
```

You may notice I added a `nested` value to the dataset. This is because it can be very difficult to track from the `onChange` event object up to the containing div with the classname "nested", i.e. there could be *any* number of elements between them, like `<label>` and other layout elements. Since you say your input fields are dynamically created it is very easy to simply add a `data-nested="nested"|""`} attribute.

```
<label>
  Name:
  <input
    data-id="test"
    data-nested=""
    name="name"
    type="text"
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
</label>

<div className="nested">
  <label>
    Nested Input 1
    <input
      data-id="test"
      data-nested="nested"
      name="value1"
      type="text"
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  </label>
</div>
```

[image: Edit how to build a nested object on handlechange]