# React - using nested objects as state with hooks to fill form data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, javascript-objects

I have a nested object as state like below -

```
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    author:"",
    user: {
      name: 'rahul',
      email: 'rahul@gmail.com',
      phone: [{ primary: '8888888810' }, { alternate: '7777777716' }]
    }
  });
```

I want to have 5 input fields - author, name, email, primary, and alternate and **want to use only one handleChange() method to change the fields**.

You can find the code I wrote on the link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ngpx7q

Here, I am not able to figure out how to update the state correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a nested object on handleChange with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200934/how-to-build-a-nested-object-on-handlechange-with-react)

Comment: Why are you using an array of objects for the phone? Just use an object.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan I was given this problem during an interview.

Comment: @MattU not exactly :(

Comment: Perhaps part of the interview was to recognize suboptimal state shape? A flat object is straightforward to work with in the UI, you can nest properties or otherwise create a new object shape when submitting to any services. Maybe the question was to identify the nested properties by dot notation, i.e. `id="user.phone.primary"` and they wanted you to write the logic to split this and recursively access the correct property. Hopefully you asked clarifying questions for what they wanted, sometimes interview questions are purposely ambiguous.

Comment: Checkout https://immerjs.github.io/immer/. For hooks implementation they have https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer

Comment: React recommends that you use [useReducer hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead of `useState`.

Comment: @DrewReese I asked clarifying questions. The interviewer asked me to use only one handleChange() to handle the input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this was an interview question then I'd avoid 3rd-party libraries. You can use a `switch` statement to handle the differently nested state, namely the `name` and `email` in the second level and `primary` and `alternate` in the third level.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;

  switch (name) {
    case "name":
    case "email":
      setUserInfo((userInfo) => ({
        user: {
          ...userInfo.user,
          [name]: value
        }
      }));
      break;

    case "primary":
    case "alternate":
      setUserInfo((userInfo) => ({
        user: {
          ...userInfo.user,
          phone: userInfo.user.phone.map((el) =>
            el.hasOwnProperty(name)
              ? {
                  [name]: value
                }
              : el
          )
        }
      }));
      break;

    default:
    // ignore
  }
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-handling-nested-objects-as-state-using-hooks]

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I am not able to change the value of alternate input in your code. I tried to debug the code but not able to find any bugs as well.

Comment: @MohitChauhan Oh, I'm terribly sorry, I used `secondary` instead of `alternate` for the second phone field name switch case in the handler. I updated my answer and linked codesandbox. Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

you can use lodash [set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) to assign the value for the deeply nested object. You need to pass the `path` to the `name` prop of your input .

```
import set from 'lodash/set'

const App = () => {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    author:"",
    user: {
      name: 'rahul',
      email: 'rahul@gmail.com',
      phone: [{ primary: '8888888810' }, { alternate: '7777777716' }]
    }
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // clone the state
    const userInfoCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userInfo));
    set(userInfoCopy, e.target.name, e.target.value)
    setUserInfo(userInfoCopy)
  }

  console.log(userInfo)

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name="user.name"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
       <input
        name="user.phone.[0].primary"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />     
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now you can use a single `handleChange` method for updating all your keys in the state .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of treating phone as object of array, which i don't think is a good idea, treat it as single object with primary and alternate as key value pairs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    user: {
      name: 'ravi',
      email: 'ravi@gmail.com',
      phone: {
        primary: 345345345345,
        alternate: 234234234234
      }
    }
  });

  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.name);
    setUserInfo(prevState => {
      return {
        user: {
          ...prevState.user,
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
          phone: {
            ...prevState.user.phone,
            ...{ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
          }
        }
      };
    });
  };

  const {
    name,
    email,
    phone: { primary, alternate }
  } = userInfo.user;

  console.log(userInfo);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Name: <input name="name" value={name} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
      <br />
      Email:{' '}
      <input name="email" value={email} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
      <br />
      Primary:{' '}
      <input name="primary" value={primary} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
      <br />
      Alternate:{' '}
      <input
        name="alternate"
        value={alternate}
        onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
      />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Giving error. Phone is not an object but an array

Answer (score 0):

This works based on your original data (where phone is an array of objects):

```js
const handleChange = e => {
    let name = e.target.name;
    if (['name', 'email'].includes(name)) {
      setUserInfo(prevState => {
        return {
          user: {
            ...prevState.user,
            [name]: e.target.value,
          }
        };
      });
    } else {
      setUserInfo(prevState => {
        return {
          user: {
            ...prevState.user,
            phone: name === 'primary' ?
             [prevState.user.phone.find(e => Object.keys(e).includes('alternate')), {[name]: e.target.value}] :
             [prevState.user.phone.find(e => Object.keys(e).includes('primary')), {[name]: e.target.value}]
          }
        };
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy paste your code and only edit your handleChange

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    user: {
      name: 'ravi',
      email: 'ravi@gmail.com',
      phone: [{ primary: '9999999990' }, { alternate: '9999998880' }]
    }
  });



  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.name);
    let arrPhone = userInfo.user.phone;
    (e.target.name == 'primary' || e.target.name == 'alternate' ) 
    && arrPhone.map(x => (x.hasOwnProperty(e.target.name)) && (x[e.target.name] = e.target.value))

    console.log(arrPhone)
    setUserInfo(prevState => {
      return {
        user: {
          ...prevState.user,
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
          phone: arrPhone
        }
      };
    });
  };

  const {
    name,
    email,
    phone: [{ primary }, { alternate }]
  } = userInfo.user;

  console.log(userInfo);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Name: <input name="name" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
      Email: <input name="email" value={email} onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
      Primary: <input name="primary" value={primary} onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
      Alternate:{' '}
      <input name="alternate" value={alternate} onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```